# Running a heroku database command from pgAdmin III? (Harry's Prelaunchr)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

so i've successfully installed Harrys Prelauncher on Heroku (https://github.com/harrystech/prelaunchr)

and to export my collected emails into a csv i need to run this command (bundle exec rake prelaunchr:create_winner_csvs)

is there any way to run that command through pgadmin or some other program?

or is the only way for me to download my heroku database and run the command locally? also how and what would i need to do this?

i'm pretty new to rails and postgresql and would really appreciate if someone could help me out!

Answer (score 2):

Because the rake task creates files locally you can't just run it on heroku via `heroku run rake`. You can however set up your local database.yml to connect to your heroku postgresql instance and run the rake task locally.

1. Run `heroku pg:credentials` to get the required database values.
2. Fill in the production environment of `config/database.yml` with the values you obtained from step 1 (for the value of 'database' in the yml file, use dbnmae from step 1)
3. Test your connection with `RAILS_ENV=production rails db`. This should drop you into a psql console.
4. Run the rake task. `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake prelaunchr:create_winner_csvs`

The files will save locally in `lib/assets` as indicated by the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

From within the directory of the project you can use

```
heroku run rake prelaunchr:create_winner_csvs
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably create a UI form in to your application.

On click on export CSV, it should run background job on heroku (Using delayed jobs).

```
heroku run rake prelaunchr:create_winner_csvs
```

Use `send_data` ruby method. To send your generated and dumped data file on to your browser.

Download the file on to your local system from running heroku instance.

Hope this will resolve your problem.

Cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem recently while developing the Prelaunchr campaign for a client. Assuming you have a local version of your app and are using Postgres Copper in Heroku, you can "pull" your Heroku database down to your local machine, set that as your development database in database.yml, and run the rake task from your local app, which should now have the same database as your heroku version. Here is the command to pull the db (subbing out name_for_database & heroku_app_name with your own):

```
heroku pg:pull HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_COPPER_URL name_for_database --app heroku_app_name
```

Make sure to restart your local server to see the new database info populated.